# Use Powershell to Publish to a WebApp Virtual Directory

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-web-app-service, azure-powershell

I have an Azure WebApp, that is [split](https://dotnetthoughts.net/deploying-multiple-application-in-webapp/) into two virtual directories - UI and API.

I've managed to create the virtual directories in code, but cannot find a means of publishing to them.

Here's my code so far:

```
# Set UI Virtaul Directory (call /ui )
$website = Get-AzWebApp -Name $appsvWebAppName -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName
 $VDApp = New-Object Microsoft.Azure.Management.WebSites.Models.VirtualApplication 
 $VDApp.VirtualPath = "/ui" 
 $VDApp.PhysicalPath = "site\wwwroot\ui" 
 $VDApp.PreloadEnabled ="YES" 
 $website.siteconfig.VirtualApplications.Add($VDApp) 
 $website | Set-AzWebApp -Verbose

# Set API Virtual Directory (call /api )
$website = Get-AzWebApp -Name $appsvWebAppName -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName
 $VDApp = New-Object Microsoft.Azure.Management.WebSites.Models.VirtualApplication 
 $VDApp.VirtualPath = "/api" 
 $VDApp.PhysicalPath = "site\wwwroot\api" 
 $VDApp.PreloadEnabled ="YES" 
 $website.siteconfig.VirtualApplications.Add($VDApp) 
 $website | Set-AzWebApp -Verbose

 $website.SiteConfig.VirtualApplications

# Dotnet publish & convert to zip here, removed for brevity ...

$uiZipPath = $zipFilesFolder + "\ui.zip"


 $publishprofile = Get-AzWebAppPublishingProfile -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName `
 -Name $appsvWebAppName `
 -OutputFile $publishProfileFileName


 Publish-AzWebApp -ArchivePath $uiZipPath `
 -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName `
 -Name $appsvWebAppName
```

I can't see how to point [Publish-AzWebApp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.websites/publish-azwebapp?view=azps-3.3.0) at a virtual directory.

The publish can be done [manually](https://dotnetthoughts.net/deploying-multiple-application-in-webapp/), but I really want to automate it (using Publish-AzWebApp or another means).

How can I do this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Publish-AzWebApp` does not support that, you could use [`Kudu API`](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/REST-API#sample-of-using-rest-api-with-powershell) in powershell to automate it.

In my sample, it uses [`VFS`](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/REST-API#vfs) to create the directory first, then upload the zip file via [`Zip`](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/REST-API#zip).

```
$appsvWebAppName = "xxxxxxx"
$resourceGroupName = "xxxxxxx"

$resource = Invoke-AzResourceAction -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -ResourceType Microsoft.Web/sites/config -ResourceName "$appsvWebAppName/publishingcredentials" -Action list -ApiVersion 2018-02-01 -Force

$username = $resource.Properties.publishingUserName
$password = $resource.Properties.publishingPassword
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $username, $password)))
$userAgent = "powershell/1.0"

# Create the folder, not lose `/` after `ui`
$apiUrl = "https://$appsvWebAppName.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/site/wwwroot/ui/"
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $apiUrl -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)} -UserAgent $userAgent -Method PUT

#Upload the zip file
$apiUrl = "https://$appsvWebAppName.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/zip/site/wwwroot/ui"
$filePath = "C:\Users\joyw\Desktop\testdep.zip"
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $apiUrl -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)} -UserAgent $userAgent -Method PUT -InFile $filePath -ContentType "multipart/form-data"
```

For the `site\wwwroot\api`, it is the same logic, just change `ui` to `api` in the script.